# User profile x permission to access pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

I'm using forms authentication to authenticate the users of my system.
The problem is the authorization, bellow, I have the table "Pages" which is the resources of system. Every user has some profile and every profile has permissions to some resources.

Here is the illustration of database:
[image]

My approach to get this work is:
On aspnet, every Page inherit a class which get Page URL and verify if logged user has permission to access the resource, if not, throw NotAuthorizedException.
The problem is that pagemethods(for jQuery access) can't be validated since this methods are static (only if I intercept Application_AuthenticateRequest on global.asax)

My question is:
Is there a better way to authorize the users respecting this database design?

Comment: Many of the features you are seeking are available in the .net Membership Roles and Profile provider framework. The only thing is you would have to tweak your tables to work with the aspnet_tables that support the framework. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

Comment: Is your authorization per page role based or per user?

Comment: Per page, users has profile and profile has permissions for pages